# JSON in R: fetching data from JSON

Tags: json, r

I have a dataframe of more than 10000 customers with 4 columns: customer_id,x,y,z

here x,y,z columns has data stored in JSON format and i want to fetch that data, consider that they took a survey and have answered different questions , some customers have less data inside these variables and some has more. But the name of the variable inside is same. I want an ouptput in a dataframe which contains customer_id and all the information available inside x,y,z

Comment: Welcome on SO! Could you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: try reading about `fromJSON` command. 
`fromJSON(content(MYdata, type = "text", encoding = "utf-8"),flatten = T,simplifyVector=T)` works for json data. you may have to separate json and non-json data and merge the converted json data at the end.

Comment: thanks for replying Philipp but I am now getting this error "is.response(x) is not TRUE" seems like httr error.. maybe you can help?

Comment: Hi I found a solution if you are still interested: I used                             
  res1<- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(mydata$x))
res2<- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(mydata$y))
res3<- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(mydata$z))

df<- cbind(res1,res2,res3)